# Connected claw free graph

Tags: graphs

So, $G$ is a connected claw free graph. How can i prove that if $M$ is a maximum matching in $G$ then $M$ exposes $at$ $most$ one vertex of $G$ ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Show that if a maximum matching exposes two vertices, then the graph contains a claw.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph#Matchings) on claw-free graphs.